# Installing/compiling pylzma (lzma python binding)

Tags: python, c, visual-c++, compiler-construction, lzma

I've already posted this question on the authors [website](http://www.joachim-bauch.de/projects/pylzma/comment-page-1/#comment-5211), but I thought I might ask here as well.

I've been trying to install pylzma with this setup:

- Windows 7 x64
- Python 2.6.6 x64
- the amd64 compiler coming from windows server 2003 sdk
- cloned the git repo git://github.com/fancycode/pylzma.git

With a simple `easy_install pylzma` I got this:

> cl : Command line warning D9025 :
>   overriding '/MD' with '/MT' pylzma.c
>   src/pylzma/pylzma.c(85) : warning
>   C4244: '=' : conversion from
>   'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss
>   of data
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(102) : error
>   C2275: 'CSha256' : illegal use of this
>   type as an expression
>           c:\users\xavier.lapointe\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2mfkqu\pylzma-0.4.3\src\pylzma../7zip/C/Sha256.h(18)
>   : see declaration of 'CSha256'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(102) : error
>   C2146: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before identifier 'sha'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(102) : error
>   C2065: 'sha' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(103) : error
>   C2065: 'sha' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(103) : warning
>   C4133: 'function' : incompatible types
>   - from 'int *' to 'CSha256 *'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(104) : error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before 'type'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(105) : error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before 'type'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(106) : error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before 'type'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(107) : error
>   C2143: syntax error : missing ';'
>   before 'type'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(108) : error
>   C2065: 'round' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(108) : error
>   C2065: 'round' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(108) : error
>   C2065: 'rounds' : undeclared
>   identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(108) : error
>   C2065: 'round' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(109) : error
>   C2065: 'sha' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(109) : warning
>   C4133: 'function' : incompatible types
>   - from 'int *' to 'CSha256 *'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(110) : error
>   C2065: 'sha' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(110) : warning
>   C4133: 'function' : incompatible types
>   - from 'int *' to 'CSha256 *'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(111) : error
>   C2065: 'sha' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(111) : warning
>   C4133: 'function' : incompatible types
>   - from 'int *' to 'CSha256 *'
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(111) : error
>   C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(112) : error
>   C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(112) : error
>   C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(112) : error
>   C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(113) : error
>   C2065: 'temp' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(113) : error
>   C2065: 'i' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(113) : error
>   C2109: subscript requires array or
>   pointer type
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(116) : error
>   C2065: 'sha' : undeclared identifier
>
> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(116) : warning
>   C4133: 'function' : incompatible types
>   - from 'int *' to 'CSha256 *'
>
> error: Setup script exited with error:
>   command '"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

Then after googling I figured it was about the compiler (c90 vs c99), some people suggested to change the .c extension to .cpp. So I did this and changed the setup.py accordingly (mostly files name).

Then success, it compiles after a few tweaks in CpuArch.c(pp) and another file which had syntax errors.

The thing is now the linker choke:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft
>   Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe /DLL /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO
>   /LIBPATH:C:\dev\pylzma\build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\pylzma
>   /LIBPATH:C:\Python26\libs
>   /LIBPATH:C:\Python26\PCbuild\amd64
>   user32.lib oleaut32.lib
>   /EXPORT:initpylzma
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_decompressobj.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_compressfile.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_decompress.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_compress.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_streams.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_aes.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_decompress_compat.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma/pylzma_decompressobj_compat.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\sdk\LzFind.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\sdk\LzmaDec.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\sdk\LzmaEnc.obj build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\7zip\C\CpuArch.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\7zip\C\Aes.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\7zip\C\AesOpt.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\7zip\C\Sha256.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src\compat\LzmaCompatDecode.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/sdk/LzFindMt.obj
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/sdk/Threads.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-2.6\pylzma.pyd
>   /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.lib
>   /MANIFESTFILE:build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.pyd.manifest
>
> pylzma.obj : warning LNK4197: export
>   'initpylzma' specified multiple times;
>   using first specification    Creating
>   library
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.lib
>   and object
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.exp
>
> pylzma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "char const * const
>   doc_decompress"
>   (?doc_decompress@@3QBDB)
>
> pylzma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "struct _object *
>   __cdecl  pylzma_decompress(struct _object *,struct _object *)" (?pylzma_decompress@@YAPEAU_object@@PEAU1@0@Z)
>
> pylzma.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved
>   external symbol "char const * const
>   doc_compress" (?doc_compress@@3QBDB)
>
> Aes.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "void __cdecl
>   AesCtr_Code_Intel(unsigned int
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCtr_Code_Intel@@YAXPEAIPEAE_K@Z)
>   referenced in function AesGenTables
>
> Aes.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "void __cdecl
>   AesCbc_Decode_Intel(unsigned int
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCbc_Decode_Intel@@YAXPEAIPEAE_K@Z)
>   referenced in function AesGenTables
>
> Aes.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol "void __cdecl
>   AesCbc_Encode_Intel(unsigned int
>   *,unsigned char *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCbc_Encode_Intel@@YAXPEAIPEAE_K@Z)
>   referenced in function AesGenTables
>
> AesOpt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _mm_aesenclast_si128
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   AesCbc_Encode_Intel(union __m128i
>   *,union __m128i *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCbc_Encode_Intel@@YAXPEAT__m128i@@0_K@Z)
>
> AesOpt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _mm_aesenc_si128
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   AesCbc_Encode_Intel(union __m128i
>   *,union __m128i *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCbc_Encode_Intel@@YAXPEAT__m128i@@0_K@Z)
>
> AesOpt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _mm_aesdeclast_si128
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   AesCbc_Decode_Intel(union __m128i
>   *,union __m128i *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCbc_Decode_Intel@@YAXPEAT__m128i@@0_K@Z)
>
> AesOpt.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved
>   external symbol _mm_aesdec_si128
>   referenced in function "void __cdecl
>   AesCbc_Decode_Intel(union __m128i
>   *,union __m128i *,unsigned __int64)" (?AesCbc_Decode_Intel@@YAXPEAT__m128i@@0_K@Z)
>   build\lib.win-amd64-2.6\pylzma.pyd :
>   fatal error LNK1120: 10 unresolved
>   externals
>
> error: command '"C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio
>   9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\link.exe"' failed with exit status 1120

Now I've a hard time trying to figure out what these linker issues are, even with the msdn doc (about linkers error). Probably due to my lack of knowledge with C/C++.

So basically my question(s) are:

- Is there a way to fix these linker issues?
- Am I wrong to rename those files from .c to .cpp. If yes, is it possible to compile it as .c with the msvc amd64 compiler?

**EDIT** 
Haven't got much answer, so I think I'll add some questions:

- What's your approach when it comes to linker error?
- Is there any logic I can follow to help myself find answers over the web (combined with this [MSDN linker errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzaatbst%28v=VS.80%29.aspx))?
- Since I've seen many people compile it successfully for 32 bit system, is it possible that it compiles fine in 64bit, but fails when it comes to linking because of the architecture type?

I'm looking more for hints that might help than a fully working answer.

Thanks a lot for your help (:

Comment: Have you tried building it with minGW?

Comment: If you've changed the filename extension to .cpp, have you ensured that the function prototypes are with an `extern "C" { ... }` block, so they don't get name mangled?

Comment: @Velociraptors Can it compiles in 64bits?

@Jack Kelly Did try to extern some part of the code based on the linker errors, but haven't check all of it (Will shortly to test it out)

Comment: I don't have a 64-bit system to test but if [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) doesn't work, you could also try the [MinGW-w64](http://mingw-w64.sourceforge.net/) project. Don't forget to revert any changes you've made to the source before compiling.

Comment: The error messages seem to suggest that the compiler is reverting to 32 bit mode.  Can you give more information about the actual commands that the compiler is running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have installed pylzma to try this out myself. For python 2.6 it builds fine with mingw, but msvc compiler chokes for python2.4-2.7. Let's see errors first:

> src/pylzma/pylzma.c(102) : error
>   C2275: 'CSha256' : illegal use of this
>   type as an expression
>   c:\users\xavier.lapointe\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-2mfkqu\pylzma-0.4.3\src\pylzma../7zip/C/Sha256.h(18) : see declaration of 'CSha256'

Code in question is:

```
} else {
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    Sha256_Init(&sha);
    CSha256 sha;
    long round;
    int i;
    long rounds = (long) 1 << cycles;
    unsigned char temp[8] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    for (round = 0; round < rounds; round++) {
```

which is clearly invalid C since it's not allowed to declare variables after code. When you renamed .c to .cpp you avoided this error since C++ allows for this (and mingw supports this for C apparently). But switching to C++ led to name mangling and linking errors. To fix those you could place `extern "C" { ... }` around all the code.

It's better to fix src/pylzma/pylzma.c htough and the fix is trivial - move Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Sha256_Init(&sha); after variable declarations:

```
} else {
    CSha256 sha;
    long round;
    int i;
    long rounds = (long) 1 << cycles;
    unsigned char temp[8] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0 };
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    Sha256_Init(&sha);
    for (round = 0; round < rounds; round++) {
```

Now pylzma compiles fine but fails to run manifest tool after linking:

> Creating library
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.lib
>   and o bject
>   build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.exp
>   C:\Program Files\Microsoft
>   SDKs\Windows\v7.0\bin\x64\mt.exe
>   -nologo -manifest bu ild\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.pyd.manifest
>   -outputresource:bu ild\lib.win-amd64-2.6\pylzma.pyd;2
>
> build\temp.win-amd64-2.6\Release\src/pylzma\pylzma.pyd.manifest
>   : general error c1010070: Failed to
>   load and parse the manifest. The
>   system cannot find the file 
>   specified. error: command 'mt.exe'
>   failed with exit status 31

Looking in build directory reveals that there is no pylzma.pyd.manifest there though it's seen from output that link.exe has /MANIFEST:... switch. Quick googling for "link didn't create manifest" finds http://bugs.python.org/issue4431 where it's explained that when using /MT switch manifest doesn't get created and the solution is to add /MANIFEST to linker flags. Alright, let's edit pylzma's setup.py to add that linker flag for MSVC compiler:

```
    if isinstance(self.compiler, MSVCCompiler):
        # set flags only available when using MSVC
        ext.extra_link_args.append('/MANIFEST') # force linker to create manifest
        if COMPILE_DEBUG:
            ext.extra_compile_args.append('/Zi')
            ext.extra_compile_args.append('/MTd')
            ext.extra_link_args.append('/DEBUG')
        else:
            ext.extra_compile_args.append('/MT')
```

Voila, pylzma builds with MSVC fine now. I have tested building with python 2.4-2.7 32-bit and 2.6-2.7 64-bit:

```
08.02.2011  10:08            71 844 pylzma-0.4.3dev-py2.4-win32.egg
08.02.2011  10:09            71 480 pylzma-0.4.3dev-py2.5-win32.egg
08.02.2011  10:07            79 358 pylzma-0.4.3dev-py2.6-win-amd64.egg
08.02.2011  10:09            75 637 pylzma-0.4.3dev-py2.6-win32.egg
08.02.2011  10:08            79 259 pylzma-0.4.3dev-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
08.02.2011  10:09            75 540 pylzma-0.4.3dev-py2.7-win32.egg
               6 File(s)        453 118 bytes
```

As of general approach to any errors - it probably requires some knowledge and experience to understand what's behind them.

Comment: You should submit your changes to [pylzma on github](https://github.com/fancycode/pylzma), since there are probably other people having the same issue.

Comment: Meanwhile Zart posted an url of the diff file on the author's website (http://aura.zartsoft.ru/~zart/pypi/pylzma-fix-msvc-compiling.diff)