# How pip install pylzma on windows 7 x64 , python 2.7

Tags: python, compilation, pip, 7zip, lzma

I assumed this should be working out of the box, but ...

i've pasted pip.log on [pastbin](http://pastebin.com/fnw0jeXD)
the last few lines of error message is

```shell
e:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DWITH_COMPAT=1 -DCOMPRESS_MF_MT=1 -Isrc/sdk -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tcsrc\7zip\C\AesOpt.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release\src\7zip\C\AesOpt.obj /MT

cl : Command line warning D9025 : overriding '/MD' with '/MT'

AesOpt.c

src\7zip\C\AesOpt.c(14) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'wmmintrin.h': No such file or directory

error: command '"e:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\BIN\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
```

via google search i found that wmmintrin.h is one of the headers comes with vc 10.0, i've installed visual studio 2010 ( contains vc 10.0 ), what i need to do is copy this file over ?

isn't pip install something supposed to be simple and painless ?

edit: i tried to copy this file into vc9's include path, but came across several different [errors](http://pastebin.com/rfjd39hY)

i have read this [Installing/compiling pylzma (lzma python binding)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4764972/installing-compiling-pylzma-lzma-python-binding)

it seems author has fix what in the setup.py and .c file already. i saw the /MANIFEST flag and  Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS and Sha256_Init(&sha) have been moved after variable declarations:

edit2: it seems vs2008(vc9) doesn't support the [compiler intrinsics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26td21ds%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) as seen in the error log, after i installed vs2008 sp1, it compiles without any error ... see [log](http://pastebin.com/Rkd87YwM)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend installing via a windows binary. It can be found at http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pylzma. This way, you don't have to worry about the stupid make errors. Trust me, you'ld waste time & energy & yet you wouldn't reap any benefits by trying to make the Visual Studio errors go away. But, if you do get success that way, please post the relevant answer here!

Comment: thanks! i tried your link, both the x86 and x64 versions, but i saw this error when trying to import pylzma
`>>> import pylzma

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pylzma
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.`

Comment: crap... i did a pip uninstall pylzma, and ran the precompiled installer again, this time it works. thanks!

Comment: If the answer solved your query, please "accept" it so as to close the question.

Comment: for anyone trying to install pylzma from [link]http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pylzma

and still failing please check the version of python with the one in the .whl file name
    pylzma-0.5.0-**cp38**-**cp38**-win_amd64.whl - > python3.8
    pylzma-0.5.0-**cp310**-**cp310**-win_amd64.whl -> python3.10